# Running distinct count in quicksight

Tags: amazon-quicksight

I want to implement a running distinct count with Amazon Quicksight. Here's an example of what that would look like:

| Date | ID | Amount | Running Distinct Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/1900 | a | 1 | 1 |
| 1/2/1900 | a | 3 | 1 |
| 1/2/1900 | b | 6 | 2 |
| 1/4/1900 | a | 3 | 2 |
| 1/8/1900 | c | 9 | 3 |
| 1/22/1900 | d | 2 | 4 |

I've tried `runningSum(distinct_count, [Date ASC])`, but this returns a sum of the distinct counts for each aggregated date field.

Can this be implemented in QuickSight?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this workaround to get the same functionality as `runningDistinctCount()` as follows:

```
runningSum(
  distinct_count(
    ifelse(
      datetime=minOver({Date}, [{ID}], PRE_AGG),
      {ID},
      NULL
    )),
  [{Date} ASC],
  []
)
```

This would give you the runningDistinctCount of `ID`'s over the `Date` field. It achieves it by considering just the first time the `ID` appears in the dataset, counting these and finally doing a runningSum on these counts.